# ¿Cómo usar window.history.back(); de JS?

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy creando una pagina web donde muestro varios videos, dependiendo de condiciones por ejemplo:

Si el usuario da clic en el menú directamente a la pagina de transmisiónmuseo.php te aparecerá algún video si coincide con la fecha y hora, si no coincida te va a mostrar otro.

Si el usuario da esta en una sección llamada todos mis videos y selecciona alguno, te manda a la pagina transmisionmuseo.php, pero con el video  seleccionado.

Dentro de esta sección tengo botones donde indica si quieres ver el video en ingles, español , francés al dar clic en un botón de estos por ejemplo a francés entonces envía una url por post con un formulario para y así sucesivamente, entonces el problema es cuando uso window.history.back(); ya que si doy clic en un botón donde tiene marcado el window.history.back(); me dice que reenvié el formulario y tengo que recargar la pagina. Utilice window.location=document.referrer; y me funciona entre comillas ya que si selecciono un video de mis videos y le doy clic al boton frances  en idioma y le doy regresar, entonces no me regresa al video seleccionado si no me manda como si estuviera dando clic desde el menu.

Dejo mi código para que se visualice como envió la url por post:

```
  <?php   
    if (!empty($url_video_es)) { $getvideorecep = $connection_video->getvideo_recep($url_video_es); ?>
  <div class="container contenerdor_video">
      <iframe src="<?php echo $url_video_es; ?>" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div style="position:fixed;  top: 16em;" class="boton_activo" id="button-forum-plenarios_activo" >
     <i class="fas fa-globe iconForo"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Audio español</b>  
  </div>
      <form action="auditorio.php" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="url_video_ori" value="<?php echo $getvideorecep["url_video_ori"] ?>">
           <button style="position:fixed; top: 24em;" id="button-forum-plenarios" ><i class="fas fa-globe iconForo"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Audio frances</b></button>
      </form>
      <form action="auditorio.php" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="url_video_en" value="<?php echo $getvideorecep["url_video_en"] ?>">
           <button style="position:fixed; top: 20em;" id="button-forum-plenarios" ><i class="fas fa-globe iconForo" ></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b id="espaciobotonEn">Audio Ingles</b></button>
      </form>  
 <?php } ?>

<?php   
    if (!empty($url_video_ori)) { $getvideorecepOri = $connection_video->getvideo_recepOri($url_video_ori); ?>
  <div class="container contenerdor_video">
      <iframe src="<?php echo $url_video_ori; ?>" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div style="position:fixed;  top: 24em;" class="boton_activo" id="button-forum-plenarios_activo" >
     <i class="fas fa-globe iconForo"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Audio Original</b>  
  </div>
      <form action="auditorio.php" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="url_video_es" value="<?php echo $getvideorecepOri["url_video_es"] ?>">
           <button style="position:fixed; top: 16em;" id="button-forum-plenarios" ><i class="fas fa-globe iconForo" ></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Audio español</b></button>
      </form> 
      <form action="auditorio.php" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="url_video_en" value="<?php echo $getvideorecepOri["url_video_en"] ?>">
           <button style="position:fixed; top: 20em;" id="button-forum-plenarios" ><i class="fas fa-globe iconForo" ></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b id="espaciobotonEn">Audio Ingles</b></button>
      </form> 
 <?php } ?>

 <?php   
    if (!empty($url_video_en)) { $getvideorecepEn = $connection_video->getvideo_recepEn($url_video_en); ?>
  <div class="container contenerdor_video">
      <iframe src="<?php echo $url_video_en; ?>" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div style="position:fixed;  top: 20em;" class="boton_activo" id="button-forum-plenarios_activo" >
     <i class="fas fa-globe iconForo"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b id="espaciobotonEn">Audio Ingles</b>  
  </div>
      <form action="auditorio.php" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="url_video_ori" value="<?php echo $getvideorecepEn["url_video_ori"] ?>">
           <button style="position:fixed; top: 24em;" id="button-forum-plenarios" ><i class="fas fa-globe iconForo" ></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Audio frances</b></button>
      </form>
      <form action="auditorio.php" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="url_video_es" value="<?php echo $getvideorecepEn["url_video_es"] ?>">
           <button style="position:fixed; top: 16em;" id="button-forum-plenarios" ><i class="fas fa-globe iconForo" ></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Audio español</b></button>
      </form> 
 <?php } ?>
```